# How to display rolling updates on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, dialog

I have a requirement to display the different stages of a Process in a dialog box overlay on the mobile app such as "Process 1 started" "Process 1 completed" "Process 2 started" and so on until the process is completed.

Essentially, what I'm looking for is scrollable text in an overlay screen appearing as the app receives different notifications(BLE characteristics). No user interaction required. Is there an out-of-the-box dialog box control that I can use? Any other suggestions for such a display?

Comment: you can simply achieve that by using a TextView ! :/

Comment: Hello @MohammedAlSafwan, TextView is too simplistic a solution. we want to show the user an overlay screen indicating progress. So a progress bar with changing message based on the process being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can add the DialogFragment and

```
if(process1.isDone())
{
informationOnDialogFragment
}

if(process2.isDone())

...
```

But the easiest way is add `ProgressDialog`
U can set message to `ProgressDialog`

Comment: Thanks. This seems closest to the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using simple toast or other innovative libraries like:
1. [EFInternetIndicator](https://github.com/ezefranca/EFInternetIndicator)
2. [FTIndicator](https://github.com/liufengting/FTIndicator)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Progress Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) . With `progress.setCancelable(false);`  you can make it so the user can`t navigate away from the dialog.